# how to return multiple variables in a function

Tags: c, return

I have been searching for the answer for this for about an hour and I am very new to C.  I am getting the warning "left-hand operand of comma expression has no affect" when referring to this line

> ```
> return studio, one, two;
> ```

The statement is not returning variables one or two to my knowledge from what my print function is showing.  Is this the correct way to return multiple variables in C or am I doing it wrong?  This is the first time I have had to do this and we didn't discuss this in my class.  Apologizes in advance for (I'm sure) a very simple fix.

Comment: If this syntax was allowed (which it isn't), how would you call the function?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes it is, but it discards both first expressions after having evaluated them.

Comment: @Quentin: Well, allowed, but unrewarding, then :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError that sums up C pretty well :p

Comment: I'm not certain the nominated duplicate is the earliest possible question (it's from 2010); there were other (later) candidate questions too.  Actually, there's an earlier question [Returning multiple values from a C function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088646/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function) from 2009 which would have been a better choice (on the basis of age).

Comment: 1) return structure 2) write to pointers passed in as arguments 3) Allocate/populate a structure and return its pointer. or 4) ugh: global variables.  #1 is best.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return multiple values in C. Your options are to return a struct, or to pass in references to the variables you want to modify:

Return struct:

```
struct studio_stuff {
   int studio;
   int one;
   int two;
};

struct studio_stuff foo()
{
   struct studio_stuff ret;
   ret.studio = 0;
   ret.one = 1;
   ret.two = 2;
   return ret;
}
```

Pass in references to modify:

```
void foo(int * studio, int * one, int * two)
{
    *studio = 0;
    *one = 1;
    *two = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return multiple values in C. You can achieve a similar (though not identical) effect by one of:

- returning a structure or (pointer to a conceptual) array.
- writing to multiple pointers passed as parameters

Comment: Note that you can't return an actual array.

Comment: Note that if you return a pointer to an array, you have to worry about memory allocation.  Embedding the array in a structure avoids that problem, but reduces to the first alternative (return a structure).  On the whole, return a structure or multiple pointer arguments are the best choices.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator evaluates its first operand, discards the result, and gives the result of the second.

So `return studio, one, two` will evaluate `studio`, discard the value, evaluate `one`, discard the value, evaluate `two` and return that value.

There is no way to return multiple values from a function.  The options are to return a struct (the value of a struct is composed of a set of values) or pass additional arguments that are pointers.  For example;

```
struct X func();
```

works because `struct X` can contain multiple values.

Alternatively

```
int func(double *y);
```

is a function that can return an int, or set the value of `*y` (which will be visible to the caller).