# Returning multiple auto_ptrs from a function

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

I have a function that allocates two variables on the heap and returns them to the caller. Something like this:

```
void Create1(Obj** obj1, Obj** obj2)
{
    *obj1 = new Obj;
    *obj2 = new Obj;
}
```

Usually, in similar cases, when I have a function with one variable I use the "source" trick with `auto_ptr`:

```
auto_ptr<Obj> Create2()
{
    return new Obj;
}
```

I would like to rewrite `Create1` using `auto_ptr` but not sure how to do it. As far as I understand I cannot return auto_ptr by reference, am I right? So is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign to a `std::auto_ptr` by calling its `reset` method:

```
void f( std::auto_ptr<Obj>& pObj1, std::auto_ptr<Obj>& pObj2 )
{
    pObj1.reset( new Obj );
    pObj2.reset( new Obj );
}
```

The `reset` call will properly delete whatever the `auto_ptr` was pointing to before.

Comment: As I understand the caller will remain the "owner" of the pointers. Looks exactly what I need. I will try it promptly.

Answer (score 4):

Related question: [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

I wouldn't expect problems using auto_ptr in a pair or tuple.  Returning a struct containing a couple of auto_ptr members should work too.

Comment: It is an option. But I'd prefer not to use pairs and structs if I could.

Comment: Timbo's answer should work if you prefer return parameters.  Personally, I dislike return parameters and avoid then whenever possible.