# Get more than one value out of an function

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

```
/************************************************/
/* Name: premserv                               */
/* Description: Calculations for premium serv   */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: premserv                       */
/************************************************/

float premserv ()
{
  int daymin = 0;         //Var for day minutes
  int nightmin = 0;       //Var for night minutes
  float daytotal = 0;     //Var for day total
  float nighttotal = 0;   //Var for night total
  float premserv = 0;     //Var for premium service cost

  cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the day (6AM - 6PM): " << "\n";
  cin >> daymin;
  cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the night (6PM - 6AM): " << "\n";
  cin >> nightmin;

  daytotal = (daymin - 75) * 0.1;
  nighttotal = (nightmin - 100) * 0.05;
  premserv = 25 + daytotal + nighttotal;

  return premserv;

}
```

I need to get the values from daymin, nightmin, and premserv out of the function. I only know how to get 1 value out of a function.

Comment: Please don't start every question title with the word "c++". That's already in the tags. Thanks.

Comment: @ Tomalak Geret'Kal: ok my bad thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [references](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html).

```
float premserv (int& daymin, int& nightmin)
{
     float daytotal = 0;     //Var for day total
     float nighttotal = 0;   //Var for night total
     float premserv = 0;     //Var for premium service cost

     cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the day (6AM - 6PM): " << "\n";
     cin >> daymin;
     cout << "\n" << "Please enter the number of minutes used durring the night (6PM - 6AM): " << "\n";
     cin >> nightmin;

     daytotal = (daymin - 75) * 0.1;
     nighttotal = (nightmin - 100) * 0.05;
     premserv = 25 + daytotal + nighttotal;

     return premserv;
}
```

This will directly modify the values of `daymin` and `nightmin` and you could still keep `premserv` as a returned value (since it fits with the function name, I guess).

You'd use it like so:

```
int daymin = 0;
int nightmin = 0;
float premiumservice = premserv(daymin, nightmin);
```

Comment: do i need to declare those variables in int main then?

Comment: @SamLaManna: Yes, they have to exist so you can pass a **reference** to them.

Comment: (I wouldn't usually make such a subjective edit, but I feel quite strongly that [this one is important for language newcomers](http://kera.name/articles/2010/05/tomalaks-monday-monstrous-rant-i-align-your-asterisks/) like the OP.)

Comment: Variable names the same as function names? Hmm... >.<

Comment: its just the return and i always assign it to a different var name in int main. premserv becomes premiumservice

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Interesting, I always used my method and thought it was just okay. I'll edit my post. (As for the variable name, yeah, sorry I did it a little quickly without thinking)

Comment: So were do i use the & and were dont I

Comment: @Jesse: Why do you keep reverting my edit if you're okay with it?

Comment: I get error: expected primary-expression before "int"   and declaration of int daymin and int nightmin shadows a parameter

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Oh really? Oh. My bad. I just moved the `&` without really thinking, telling myself that I had to move it to the opposite of what it was. I did not notice your edit. Thank you, though.

Comment: @Sam: Then you're not using the code that Jesse showed you.

Comment: Here is the whole thing, with all changes made:  [link]http://pastebin.com/NnrxnVHU

Comment: @SamLaManna: Remove the `int`s when calling the function. You are passing the variable name, not its type. That's how the syntax of references works. :)

Comment: Thanks but i still have  an error: 'declaration of 'int daymin' shadows a parameter'.  The same thing for nightmin

Comment: @SamLaManna: remove the declarations of `daymin` and `nightmin` within the function. You're passing the references, so you don't need to redeclare them once again, since you just pass them to the function. i.e. get rid of those lines:
int daymin = 0;         //Var for day minutes
int nightmin = 0;       //Var for night minutes

Answer (score 8):

Create a struct with all three floats and return that instead of the single float.

Answer (score 1):

in c, create a structure to hold above said 3 values. in c++ create a class and return an object of the class.

Comment: You said the same thing twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
float premserv(int& daymin, int& nightmin) { 
    float daytotal = 0;     //Var for day total    
    float nighttotal = 0;   //Var for night total    
    float premserv = 0;     //Var for premium service cost    
    // etc...
```

'premserv' is already being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides using out parameters or defining a specific struct return type is to use tuples from C++11 or TR1:

```
/* Return Value: tuple<daymin,nightmin,premserv>   */
/***************************************************/

std::tuple<int,int,float> premserv ()
{
  // ...
  return std::make_tuple(daymin, nightmin, premiumservice);
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
int daymin, nightmin;
float premiumservice;
std::tie(daymin,nightmin,premiumservice) = premserv();
```

Or if you just care about one of the values:

```
int nightmin = std::get<1>(premserv());
```

Answer (score 0):

You got multipel answers but alternatively you can return struct in the function parameter so you have one object to deal with and return value will tell you if the data is valid or not.

```
struct
{
   float premserv;
   int daymin;
   int nightmin;

} data;

bool premserv (data & my_data)
{
   // ...
}

if( premserv(my_data) == true )
{
  // user the data
}
```