# C++ parameter is a pointer to a constant object but the updated object is not returned?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, vector, constants

I have native C++ class `SrcClass` containing the following:

```
std::vector<shotEntry> objectsQueue;

bool getRelatedEntry(const entryToProcess *entriesDeets, int &i) const {
    if (i >= (int)objectsQueue.size()) {
        i = 0;
        return false;}
    if (!objectsQueue.size()) return false;
    entriesDeets = &(objectsQueue[i++]);
    return true;
}
```

In my client I have:

```
const entryToProcess *entriesDeets = NULL;
int i = 0;
while (srcObj->getRelatedEntry(entriesDeets, i)) {
```

When I step through `getRelatedEntry` the formal parameter, `entriesDeets` is updated as expected before returning. When it returns the actual parameter of the client is not updated.

This is in some big project I have returned to after two months away. I'm pretty sure the last refactoring I did was to introduce these *damnable* `vectors`. It takes ages to compile when I mess with headers. Am I getting confused with the initialize once/ readonly/ const'ness of C#? Can I get away with the client getting a read only native object back?

Comment: You might be interested in other ways to return multiple values from a function: http://stackoverflow.com/q/321068/10077

Comment: Be careful when using pointers to objects inside a vector.  If items are added to the vector, reallocation may happen, everything will move, and your pointers will be invalid.

Comment: My code is entirely synchronous apart from any threads the UI employs. I am literally just grabbing the pointer, updating it to screen and then discarding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are setting the value of the function's parameter. You want:

```
bool getRelatedEntry(const entryToProcess **entriesDeets, int &i) const {
    ...
    *entriesDeets = &(objectsQueue[i++]);
    ...
```

and

```
srcObj->getRelatedEntry(&entriesDeets, i)
```

Comment: Or as Benamin Lindley said, a reference to a pointer: `bool getRelatedEntry(const entryToProcess *&entriesDeets, int &i) const {` and no other changes are needed.

Comment: But `**` is more readable than `*&` where you might have to understand associativity.

Answer (score 3):

entriesDeets is a local variable inside getRelatedEntry.  You only modified the local, you didn't affect the value passed in.  You need to pass a reference to pointer or a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer is updated, but it is the internal copy inside the function. If you want that change to be visible outside of the function, you should pass a reference:

```
//                                         v
bool getRelatedEntry(const entryToProcess *&entriesDeets, int &i) const {
```

Or in C style a double pointer and dereference it internally on every usage:

```
//                                         v
bool getRelatedEntry(const entryToProcess **entriesDeets, int &i) const {
   // ...
   *entriesDeets = &(objectsQueue[i++]);
```