# C++ functions won't return values

Tags: c++, function, debugging

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

//Functions
// player strategy
int strategy(int user1Strat, int user2Strat);
// player total score per round
int currentScore();
// Display game result
void printResults();

int main()
{
    int total_player1 = 0; // player 1 current score
    int total_player2 = 0; // player 2 current score
    int player1_strat= 0;  //player 1 strategy for each turn
    int player2_strat = 0; // player 2 strategy for each turn

    // seed the random number generator.
    srand(static_cast<int> (time(NULL)));

    // get strategy for each player using functions <strategy>

    strategy(player1_strat, player2_strat);

    cout << player1_strat << endl << player2_strat << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int strategy(int user1Strat, int user2Strat)
{
    int x,
        y;

    cout << "Enter player1's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user1Strat;
    cout << "Enter player2's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user2Strat;
    x = user1Strat;
    y = user2Strat;

    return x, y;
}
```

While calling for function `strategy` in the function `main` it will execute how it should, but once I ask to return the value it will just return

```
Enter player1's roll until strategy: 10
Enter player2's roll until strategy: 5

0
0

press any key to contiue...
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or what is causing it, was my error in the strategy function? Or upon calling it?

Comment: That's not how you return multiple values in C++ from a function. Look up "returning by reference".

Comment: Your understanding of returning values from functions is flawed. Please read a textbook on the subject.

Comment: Also you don't take any return value from the function anyway. X and y don't magically appear on some random variables you would like. A basics tutorial/book will help you here.

Comment: The `strategy` function should return a `std::pair<int,int>`, not a single `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning two variables in a C++ function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365860/returning-two-variables-in-a-c-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strategy(player1_strat, player2_strat);` in your `main()` do nothing after receiving inputs so you won't see any change on `player1_strat` and `player2_strat`.

If you want to modify `player1_strat` and `player2_strat` in `strategy`, you could do that by referencing:

```
void strategy(int& user1Strat, int& user2Strat)
{
    cout << "Enter player1's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user1Strat;
    cout << "Enter player2's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user2Strat;
}
```

or you could return "multiple value" by using `std::pair`:

```
//#include <utility>
std::pair<int, int> strategy(int user1Strat, int user2Strat)
{
    int x, y;

    cout << "Enter player1's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user1Strat;
    cout << "Enter player2's roll until strategy: ";
    cin >> user2Strat;
    x = user1Strat;
    y = user2Strat;

    return std::make_pair(x, y);
}

//main()
std::pair<int, int> result = strategy(player1_strat, player2_strat);

x = result.first;
y = result.second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single object from a function. `return x, y;` does not return `x` and `y` but only `y`. If you want to update multiple variables, give them to the function as references and change their value inside the function.

Edit:

As mentioned by @Keith Thompson in the comments, the comma actually is an operator in this statement. It evaluates `x` (not much to do there), discards the result and then evaluates and returns the second argument `y`.

Comment: *`return x, y;` is not allowed.* It is syntactically valid. It doesn't do what the OP is expecting.

Comment: @RSahu You are right that was not precise. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: eh, would "return x, y" return x and treat "y" as another expression by itself?

Comment: You should mention the comma operator.

Comment: @KeithThompson True. Updated my answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @user3109672: `return x, y;` is equivalent to `return(x, y);` — that is, `x` is evaluated and the result discarded, then `y` is evaluated and the value of `y` is returned.  Normally, the evaluation of `x` will have some side-effect; here is doesn't, and a compiler would probably warn about that (at least if warnings and/or optimization is enabled).