# C++ returning more than once?

Tags: c++, return

Is this ever valid? Will the project compile? I do not have access to a compiler right now, but my friend had this in his code:

```
int returnTwice () {
  return 1;
  return 2;
}
```

Why and how is this inappropriate?

Thank you!

Thank you everyone that had something constructive to say.

Comment: And by "friend" you mean "homework assignment"?

Comment: If you have internet, then you have a compiler. http://ideone.com

Comment: Sure you have access to a compiler: http://ideone.com just for example.

Comment: No, I am reading my friends code and I have a question to ask. There's no need to assume this is a homework question just because the majority of the questions posted here are. If you don't want to answer my question, don't post.

Comment: This doesn't compile!

Comment: The problem in this code is not the double return.

Comment: Then why don't you ask your friend?

Comment: I was writing up a comment, but decided to post it as an answer instead- please see it.

Answer (score 4):

It's *partly* valid.

The invalid part is that you try to declare a variable in an expression, which is not allowed. But there's nothing illegal by having multiple unconditional `return` statements, however only the first will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible in C++ or any other programming language that I know of.

As another user who answered your question said, *only the first `return` statement will be executed*. Depending entirely on the compiler, it *might* give you an error or warning that you have two `return` functions in one defined scope, *there is no syntax error here.*

It is possible to return two or more values in C++ by placing each variable into a vector and returning it, as [documented in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

A `return` returns the value assigned to it and exits the function.

In other programming languages such as `Lua` a `return variable1, variable2;` can be used.

Comment: It is also the case in Python (more popular than Lua in my opinion).

Comment: @Caduchon I believe that `return`ing in this way is supported in most 'raw' languages, `PHP` definitely does and I think `Java` does too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in C++. But, if you want a similar behaviour, you can use `boost::tuple`.

```
boost::tuple<double,double> figInfo(const Figure& fig)
{
  double p = fig.getPerimeter();
  double s = fig.getSurface();
  return boost::make_tuple(p,s);
}

boost::tuple<std::string, unsigned short int, std::string> profile()
{
  std::string first_name = "Christophe";
  unsigned short int age = 29;
  std::string address = "Unspecified";
  return boost::make_tuple(first_name, age, address);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

When a function returns, it stops executing. Everything after the first return executed will never get executed. Thus, you should get an "Error: unreachable code" for such a function.

Comment: It would be a warning, not an error, and it's completely at the discretion of the compiler - the standard doesn't mandate it.

Comment: Yeah, I always thought it would be better as a warning. I just never saw it that way.