# Return Multiple Values C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, return

Is there a way to return multiple values from a function? In a program I'm working on, I wish to return 4 different int variables to the main function, from a separate function, all stats needed to continue through the program. I've found no way to really do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There's [a sample for this on C++ Samples](http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/return-multiple-values.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to return a vector from your function :

```
std::vector<int> myFunction()
{
   std::vector<int> myVector;
   ...
   return myVector;
}
```

Another solution would be to add out parameters :

```
int myFunction(int *p_returnValue1, int *p_returnValue2, int *p_returnValue3)
{
   *p_var1 = ...;
   *p_var2 = ...;
   *p_var3 = ...;
   return ...;
}
```

In the second example, you'll want to declare the four variables that will contain the four results of your code.

```
int value1, value2, value3, value4;
```

After that, you call your function, passing  the address of each of your variables as parameters.

```
value4 = myFunction(&value1, &value2, &value3);
```

EDIT : This question has been asked before, flagging this as duplicate.
[Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

EDIT #2 : I see multiple answers suggesting a struct, but I don't see why "declaring a struct for a single function" is relevant when their are obviously other patterns like out parameters that are meant for problems like this.

Comment: Is there an issue with my answer? A comment would be appreciated so I can edit/delete the answer.

Comment: Nope! It was perfect, thanks

Answer (score 8):

With C++11 and beyond, you can use `std::tuple` and `std::tie` to do programming that is very much in the style of languages like Python's ability to return multiple values. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int, int, int> bar() {
    return std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4);
}

int main() {

    int a, b, c, d;

    std::tie(a, b, c, d) = bar();

    std::cout << "[" << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << ", " << d << "]" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And if you have C++14, this becomes even cleaner since you don't need to declare the return type of `bar`:

```
auto bar() {
    return std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

C++ doesn't support returning multiple values, but you can return single values of types which contain instances of other types. For example,

```
struct foo
{
  int a, b, c, d;
};

foo bar() {
  return foo{1, 2, 3, 4};
}
```

Or

```
std::tuple<int, int, int, int> bar() {
  return std::make_tuple(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Or, in C++17, you will be able to use *structured bindings*, which allow you to initialize multiple objects from functions returning types representing multiple values:

```
// C++17 proposal: structured bindings
auto [a, b, c, d] = bar(); // a, b, c, d are int in this example
```

Comment: okay, so then how would I save those 4 return values as a variable back in main? Would they just automatically overwrite what they were before, or will I have to manually make them do that somehow? Sorry, I'm still very new with C++.

Comment: Pretty sure that's why I'm here, but thanks anyways.

Comment: See my answer on how to use `std::tie` on the return side.

Answer (score 2):

If the type of all variables you wish top return is the same, you can just return an array of them:

```
std::array<int, 4> fun() {
    std::array<int,4> ret;
    ret[0] = valueForFirstInt;
    // Same for the other three
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function which takes 4 `int`s as references.

```
void foo(int& a, int& b, int& c, int& d)
{
    // Do something with the ints
    return;
}
```

Then use it like

```
int a, b, c, d;
foo(a, b, c, d);
// Do something now that a, b, c, d have the values you want
```

However, for this particular case (4 ints) I would recommend @juanchopanza's answer (std::tuple). I added this approach for completeness.