# How to return multiple values from a function in c++?

Tags: c++

I know this has been asked before but I still don't know how to do it. I Have to write a function which returns the number of times 2, 5 and 9 appear in an array.

```
    include <iostream>

    int twofivenine(int array[], int n)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int num_2 = 0;
        int num_5 = 0;
        int num_9 = 0;

        for ( i = 0;  i < n; i++ ){
            switch(){
                case (array[i] == 2):
                    num_2++;
                case (array[i] == 5):
                    num_5++;
                case (array[i] == 9):
                    num_9++;
            }

        }

       return ;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int array[6] = {2,2,3,5,9,9};

        std::cout << "2: 5: 9:" << twofivenine(array, 6) << std::endl;
    }
```

I'm just not sure how to return (num_2, num_5, and num_9)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Comment: it was asked many times before, did you do a search before asking?

Comment: It has been asked, but the top answers look pretty confusing, especially for someone new to C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can use [*`std::tuple`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

```
std::tuple<int, int, int > twofivenine( int array[], int n)
{
  // 
  return make_tuple( num_2, num_5, num_9 );
}

  auto x = twofivenine( array, 6 );
  std::cout << std::get<0>( x ) << '\n'
            << std::get<1>( x ) << '\n'
            << std::get<2>( x ) << '\n' ;
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to approach this problem.

1. **Pass the values by reference.**  You can call a function such as the following:

Example:

```
void foo(int &a, int &b, int &c)
{
    // modify a, b, and c here
    a = 3
    b = 38
    c = 18
}

int first = 12;
int second = 3;
int third = 27;
foo(first, second, third);
// after calling the function above, first = 3, second = 38, third = 18
```

2. **Store the values to return in a data type.**  Use a data type from the standard library such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), etc. to hold your values then return that entire data member.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> foo()
{
    std::vector<int> myData;
    myData.pushBack(3);
    myData.pushBack(14);
    myData.pushBack(6);
    return myData;
}
// this function returns a vector that contains 3, 14, and 6
```

3. **Create an object to hold your values.** Create an object such as a [`struct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) or a [`class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) to hold your values and return the object in your function.

Example:

```
struct myStruct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

myStruct foo()
{
    // code here that modifies elements of myStruct
    myStruct.a = 13;
    myStruct.b = 2;
    myStruct.c = 29;
    return myStruct;
}
// this function returns a struct with data members a = 13, b = 2, and c = 29
```

The method you choose will ultimately depend on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

Pass objects in by reference, ie

```
void twofivenine(int array[], int n, int &num_2, int &num_5, int &num_9)
{
    //Don't redeclare num_2...
}
```

Call like so:

```
int num_2, num_5, num_9;
twofivenine(array, 6, num_2, num_5, num_9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a struct by value which has the counts as the data members:

```
struct Result {
   int num_3;
   int num_5;
   int num_9;
};

Result twofivenine(int array[], int n)
{
.
.
.
    return Result{num_2, num_5, num_9};
}
```

and in main:

```
Result result(twofivenine(array, 6));
std::cout << "2: " << result.num_2 << "5: " << result.num_5 << "9: " << result.num_9 << std::endl;
```

Most compilers will do RVO (return-value-optimization) where the twofivenine function will directly write to the result struct avoiding a struct copy.