# How to round float to up and down value c++ with own function?

Tags: c++, function, rounding

```cpp
double round(double a)
{
    double b, c, f, g;
    float d[2];
    c = modf(a, &b);
    if (a > 0) {
        f = a - c;
        g = a - c + 1;
        d[0] = f;
        d[1] = g;
        return d[0], d[1];
    }
    else {
        f = a - c;
        g = a - c - 1;
        d[0] = f;
        d[1] = g;
        return d[0], d[1];
    }
}
```

I need to get 2 numbers it the end(for ex: if I have num 12.34, I want to get 12 and 13)This is my function of rounding for pos and neg numbers. But it returns only 1 value(( So I'm stack...pls, help how to return 2 values?

Comment: Use `floor` and `ceil`?

Comment: (int)12.34 = 12, (int)12.34 + 1 = 13

Comment: or `std::floor(d)` and `std::floor(d) +1`. depends if you want `{12, 12}` or `{12, 13}` for `12.0`.

Comment: "it doesn't work" in which way?

Comment: Read attentively - OWN function, I don't need to use build-in functions

Comment: If `a` is an integer, for instance, `a=12.0`, then which values do you need? `{12,12}`, `{11,12}` or `{12,13}`?

Comment: does no matter now

Comment: @ЯрославМашко `(int)12+1=13` - oops.

Comment: `return d[0], d[1];` um... Do you know what that returns?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function

Comment: The expected behavior in the corner cases is key to provide a solution other than a [trivial one](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ChydsmoQ9hlG9Ini).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin My mistake. Above comments clearly show that one needs some kind of check for fraction.

Comment: What's wrong with [the standard rounding functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) including [std::floor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/floor) & [std::ceil](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil)? Why re-invent the wheel by rolling your own function?

Comment: It's my control work at school)

Comment: You don't really need to return multiple values. Just return the smaller of the two values. The other value will always be one more than the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

auto rounding(double x)
{
    int part = static_cast<int>(x);
    if (x < 0.0)
    {
        return array<int, 2> {
            part - 1, part
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return array<int, 2> {
            part, part + 1
        };
    }
}

int main()
{
    double x;
    cout << "Please, enter a float number to round: ";
    cin >> x;

    auto r1 = rounding(x);
    if (x > 0) {
        cout << "A lower value: " << r1[0] << endl << "A bigger value: " << r1[1];
    }
    else {
        cout << "A bigger value: " << r1[0] << endl << "A lower value: " << r1[1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot return two things in the return, so `return d[0],d[1]` compiles but doesn't work as you expect. You can use two reference parameters in the function prototype to return. Something like `void round(double a, double* result1, double* result2)`. Into the function, set `d[0]` to `*result1` and `d[1]` to `*result2`.

Another thing: Are you sure the line `g = a - c - 1;` when a is negative is correct? I think you need to do `g = a + c - 1;`, because a is negative.