# C++ return value type (integer) does not match the function type

Tags: c++, function, return-type

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


void randNum()
{
    int num1 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int num2 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int answer;
    answer = num1 * num2;

    return answer, num1, num2;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```

I get the error return value type does not match the function type.  Answer is an integer but it won't return regardless.

Comment: Look at the return type of your function (`void`). Does that match what you're returning? Further, that isn't how you return multiple values from a C function. You either must pass the values as in/out arguments by address, or return a structure defined to hold the values in question. This code does neither. `return answer, num1, num2;` is ultimately `return num2;` which is highly likely *not* what you intended.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/321080/509868

Comment: Due to the number of questions like this I see, I consider there needs to be a `incorrect-programming-language-reuse` tag on SO with a description "The question was asked due to an unchecked and incorrect assumption that syntax from programming language X will work in exactly the same way in completely different programming language Y." - in this case the X is Python and Y is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return 3 things. You may wrap it in a struct if you wish. And make your function return the struct instead of void. In main, call your function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


struct three_values {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

three_values randNum()
{
    three_values return_me;
    int num1 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int num2 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int answer;
    answer = num1 * num2;
    return_me.a = num1;
    return_me.b = num2;
    return_me.c = answer;
    return return_me;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    three_values var = randNum();

    std::cout << "num_1 = " << var.a << ", " << "num_2 = " << var.b << std::endl;
    std::cout << var.a << "*" << var.b << " = " << var.c << std::endl;
}
```

Possible output:

```
num_1 = 6, num_2 = 7                                                         
6*7 = 42
```

Comment: You are mixing C and C++ here.   After defining the `struct` type `three_values`, the `struct` keyword is not required to use it.   And, idiomatically, doing so is considered quite poor practice in C++, even though it is technically allowed due to backward compatibility with C.

Comment: At the risk of seeming completely immodest, I know.

Comment: Well, you don't really need to define a struct in this case. Can very well use C++11's [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), since that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared to return void, in C++ this means it doesn't return anything.
You first need to change the function signature return type to the type you planned to return (for instance int).

Additionally, as written already - in C++ you can't return several variables like you do in Python. You can pass back values through references or pointers in the function's parameter or through a return of a struct that contains all these values.

Answer (score 0):

look at your code! you are trying to return a value from a **void** function and returning multiple values. This is totally wrong. Rather then **Void randNum()**
you should use ***int randNum()***. And return only answer.

this is correct code>>

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int randNum()
{
    int num1 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int num2 = (rand() % 12) + 1;
    int answer;
    answer = num1 * num2;

    return answer;
}
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
}
```