# How do I return multiple values in a function C++?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, return

I am writing some code and ran into an error when I need to return multiple values to `main()` from another function.

Here, I am trying to return `item` and `total` to the `main()` function.  However, I am getting a warning saying that `item` has not been used, but I am using it in `main()`, where it then says "use of undeclared identifier" along with `total`.

Could someone help me with my syntax issue here?

```
int processSelection() {
  cout << "Enter your selection: " << flush;
  int item;
  cin >> item;

  cout << menuItems[item-1] << ": $" << cost[item-1] << " has been added to cart." << endl;

  int total;
  total = 0;
  total = total + cost[item];
  
  return (item, total);
}

int main() {
  cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
  cout << "----Items------" << endl;

  vendingMachine();
  cout << "Enter 0 to checkout" << endl;

  int selection(item) = processSelection();

  float cost;
  
  while(selection != 0) {

    processSelection();
  } 
  cout << "Proceding to checkout..." << endl;
  cout << "========================" << endl;
  
  cout << "Amount due: " << total << endl;
```

Edited code: (I still get an error for `return std::make_pair(item, total);` and `p = processSelection();`)

```
int processSelection() {
  cout << "Enter your selection: " << flush;
  int item;
  cin >> item;

  cout << menuItems[item-1] << ": $" << cost[item-1] << " has been added to cart." << endl;

  int total;
  total = 0;
  total = total + cost[item];
  
  return std::make_pair(item, total);

}

int main() {
  cout << "Vending Machine" << endl;
  cout << "----Items------" << endl;

  vendingMachine();
  cout << "Enter 0 to checkout" << endl;

//  int selection() = processSelection();
  std::pair<int, int> p = processSelection();

  float cost;
  
  while(p.first != 0) {

    processSelection();
  } 
  cout << "Proceding to checkout..." << endl;
  cout << "========================" << endl;
  
  cout << "Amount due: " << p.second << endl;
```

Comment: check this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function-using-tuple-and-pair-in-c/

Comment: Looks like you're wanting to return `std::pair<int,int>`

Comment: Marginally related, but worth your time to read so you know what the comma operator does in C++: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator

Comment: Use pairs, tuples, structures or clases. Or (less recommended) non-const reference arguments.

Comment: My suggestion is using a `struct` which provides more meaningful info about what first and second values are rather than just "first and second".

Comment: how do i use pairs here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below in your processSelection referencing https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-multiple-values-from-a-function-using-tuple-and-pair-in-c/ from Mike.

```
return std::make_pair(item, total);
```

and call using in your main.

```
std::pair<int, int> p = processSelection();
```

Then you can use p.first and p.second to access the values.

As well as change int processSelection() to  std::pair<int, int> processSelection()

Comment: An other choice to handle return is using `std::tie`.

Comment: I tried it but "std::make_pair(item, total);" (the first line you suggested) gives me this error: " [cquery] no viable conversion from returned value of type 'pair<typename __decay_and_strip<int &>::__type, typename __decay_and_strip<int &>::__type>' (aka 'pair<int, int>') to function return type 'int'"

Comment: Change int processSelection() to std::pair<int, int> processSelection()

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared to return a single `int`, but then you try to `return` multiple `int` values.  That will simply not work.

You need to change the function to return a type that can actually hold multiple values at a time, eg:

```
struct ItemTotal {
    int item;
    int total;
};

ItemTotal processSelection() {
    ItemTotal it;
    ...
    it.item = ...;
    it.total = ...;
    ...
    return it;
}

int main() {
    ...
    ItemTotal selection = processSelection();
    // use selection.item and selection.total as needed...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but I am not sure what to put after the it.item = ...; and it.total = ...;

Answer (score 0):

You could just declare 'item' and 'total' in the main function and pass their reference to the processSelection() function like so:

```
void processSelection(int &item,int &total)
```