# How to pair 2D array and integer in the output of the function?

Tags: c++, function, c++11

I'm struggling to create multi-variable output from a function: I want to return 2D array *sites(16x15)* and the integer number *N*.

I tried:

1. [std::make_tuple here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)
2. [std:make_pair here](https://www.techiedelight.com/return-multiple-values-functions-cpp/)

My problem is that I probably do not know how to define a 2D array in the declaration of the function *std::pair **<int [][]**,int>* correctly.

Piece of code named function.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

std::pair <int[16][15],int> sites_diamond()
{
    int sites[16][15]={0};
    int N=0;
    for (int r=0; r<7; r++) {
        N=N+1+2*r;
        for (int c=0; c<(7-r);c++){
            sites[r][c]=0;
            sites[15-r][c]=0;
            sites[r][14-c]=0;
            sites[15-r][14-c]=0;
        }
    }
    N=2*(N+15);
    return std::make_pair(sites, N);
}

using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::pair <int[16][15], int> result = sites_diamond();
    cout << " sites \n"<<result.first<< endl;
    cout << "number \n"<<result.second<< endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Error I'm getting:

```
function.cpp: In function ‘std::pair<int [16][15], int> sites_diamond()’:
function.cpp:21:26: error: could not convert ‘std::make_pair<int (&)[16][15], int&>(sites, N)’ from ‘std::pair<int (*)[15], int>’ to ‘std::pair<int [16][15], int>’
     return std::make_pair(sites, N);
```

Thank you ahead for any suggestions.
I work primarily in Python, but I want to rewrite a code to C++.

Comment: Instead of the raw array definiton, rather use `std::array<std::array<int,15>,16>`. That will make dealing with the array as value a lot easier.

Comment: I assume that the posted code isn't the real one (it's assigning zero values to the arrays multiple times), but is it correct to state that the value of N only depends by 15 and 16?

Comment: Please check out the answers and mark the one that solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with `std::array`. It is more C++-ish and you don't need to care about memory allocation/deallocation.

```cpp
std::pair <std::array<std::array<int, 15>, 16>, int> sites_diamond()
{
    std::array<std::array<int, 15>, 16> sites;
    // ...
    return std::make_pair(sites, N);
}
```

and then the usage would be:

```cpp
auto result = sites_diamond();
cout << " sites \n"  << result.first.size() << endl;
cout << " number \n" << result.second       << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error is quite explanatory, I will just suggest the solution. Use pointers.
Define your pair like this:

```
std::pair<int**, int> result;
```

Of-course, inside your function, change how you define sites:

```
int **sites;
sites = new int*[16];
for (int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
    sites[i] = new int[15];
```

Regarding

```
cout << " sites \n"<<result.first<< endl;
```

I don’t know what are you trying to print here, it's gonna print some random address anyway.

Don’t forget to `delete` this dynamically allocated memory when you are done.
But all in all, I would just suggest to use something like vectors (2-d vector in this case, leak-proof too) in place of C-styled arrays.