# How to return two values in a C++ function

Tags: c++, function

I am trying to write a function in c++ to calculate the sum and product
so my code is like that:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int Product_Sum(int x, int y, int z)
{
int sum, product;
sum = x + y + z;
product = x * y * z;

return sum, product;
}

int main() {
int result;
int x = 5, y = 10, z = 15;
result = Product_Sum(x, y, z);

cout << result;
enter code here

}
```

as a result I am just getting the sum of the numbers, how I can return both values together ?
I tried writing it with retrurning 0 but I think it's not the right way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Comment: `std::pair<int, int>` or dedicated struct.

Comment: you can only return one value, but you can return a value of type `struct product_and_sum { int product; int value; };`

Comment: fwiw, you should initialize variables already when you declare them, ie `int sum = x + y + z;` rather than `int sum; sum = x+y+z;`. Uninitialized variables can easily lead to hard to detect bugs (undefined behavior) and it is much harder to make such mistakes when you write `int sum = x+y+z;`

Comment: Instead of returning you can have additional parameters passed by reference ie `bool Product_Sum(int x, int y, int z, someStructContainingMultipleResults & result)` and the bool return type can be used to indicate successful execution vs error cases ie divide by zero, usage can be now `if(Product_Sum(....) ) {//do something useful}`

Comment: @saumitramallick: I would avoid output parameters. You have `std::optional`/exception (and proposals for `std::expected<T, E>` or equivalent) to handle error.