# error: invalid declarator before function_name

Tags: c++, function, methods, std-pair

I have the following bit of code to return the scaled down value and its respective unit of measurement:

```
enum class convert_mode {up_metric, low_metric, metric, bit_metric, imperial}

std::pair <double, std::string> auto_range (uint64_t x, int factor1 = 1000, int factor2 = 10){

        double val = (double) x;
        int i = 0;
        while (val >= factor1 ){
                val = val / factor1;
                i++;
                }
        switch (i) {
                case 0 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"_" );
                case 1 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"K" );
                case 2 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"M" );
                case 3 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"G" );
                case 4 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"T" );
                case 5 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"P" );
                }
        
        return std::make_pair(0,"_");
        }
```

that returns me the following error at compilation:

```
get_info.cpp:41:33: error: invalid declarator before ‘auto_range’
   41 | std::pair <double, std::string> auto_range (uint64_t x, int factor1 = 1000, int factor2 = 10){
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
get_info.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
get_info.cpp:270:14: error: ‘auto_range’ was not declared in this scope
  270 |   auto x1 =  auto_range(PC.get_memory_info(), factor1, factor2);
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
```

As a side-note the code did compile correctly previously and I inspired this method from the following answer : [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Edit:

- The function should work like this:

1. auto_range ( number_to_reduce, reduction_per_unit, reduction_of_digits )
2. returns pair< reduced_number, unit_of_measurement >

- digit_rm is a function to remove the extardigits remained after the comma (12345m => 12.345Km => digit_rm(12.345,10) => 12.3Km).

```
double digit_rm (double val, int factor = 100){
    return (double)((int)(val*factor))/factor; 
    }
```

- may `#include`'s in this case are the following :

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>  // std::seprecision, std::fixed 
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
// See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
```

- I am using a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64), if that matters.
- The `enum class` is a part of a future modification, if that is worth mentioning.
- Here is an example :

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>  // std::seprecision, std::fixed 
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
// See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>

double digit_rm (double val, int factor = 100){
    return (double)((int)(val*factor))/factor; 
    }

enum class convert_mode {up_metric, low_metric, metric, bit_metric, imperial}

std::pair < double, std::string > auto_range (uint64_t x, int factor1 = 1000, int factor2 = 10){

    double val = (double) x;
    int i = 0;
    while (val >= factor1 ){
        val = val / factor1;
        i++;
        }
    switch (i) {
        case 0 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"_" ); 
        case 1 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"K" ); 
        case 2 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"M" ); 
        case 3 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"G" );
        case 4 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"T" );
        case 5 : return std::make_pair( digit_rm( val, factor2 ) ,"P" ); 
        }
    
    return std::make_pair(0,"_");
    }

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

double x = 1234567;          //say this is Hz
auto y = auto_range(x);
std::cout << y.first << " " << y.second << "Hz" << std::endl;    //Should return 1.2Mhz

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "the scaled down value," like we know the intimate details of what you're working on. It looks like you're missing an include, but your [mre] is not reproducible enough to know that for sure.

Comment: What is `digit_rm`?

Comment: Missing semi colon at end of enum?

Comment: (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻ ..........(－‸ლ)