# Is there a solution to override an argument in C++?

Tags: c++

I just found something that I cant understand. I have a function that I want not only run in main(), but to use it in another function (for edit file) and I dont want to create an extra global variables.

```
int fileOut(bool = 1, char filename[] = 0);

//...

int fileOut(bool output, char filename[15]){
    cin >> filename; // and if I do so, Ill got the error like this:
                     // Exception thrown: Write access violation. _Str was 0x1110112. 
    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Soo, is theres a solution how to fix this and make possible change filename?

Comment: use a string object

Comment: What is the purpose of `fileOut()`?

Comment: `cin >> filename` creates a nice buffer overflow attack vector.

Comment: @FredLarson im gonna read file and output result in table

Comment: @SaMartinell: `fileOut()` is going to do all that?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, I think its exactly what I wanted to see

Comment: @FredLarson yes, why`re u asking?

Comment: @SaMartinell: So why is `filename` a parameter, rather than just a local variable?

Comment: @FredLarson Oh, I have another function to edit file and I`d input filename there and then make fileOut(1, filename) to put data in struct, then edit structure and save file. Without this parameter ill have to input filename in editfile twice

Comment: @SaMartinell: Ah, so you want the file name to be returned. You might consider reading my question [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/321068/10077).

Comment: @FredLarson This is might be the way, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a function parameter, `char filename[15]` is actually treated by the compiler as simply `char *filename`, which you are defaulting to `0`, aka `NULL`/`nullptr`.  So, if the caller doesn't provide a buffer for `filename`, it won't point anywhere useful, so you can't write data to it, hence the crash.

In that situation, you can use a local variable to write to, eg:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool output, char filename[15]){
    char buffer[15] = {};
    if (!filename) filename = buffer;

    cin >> filename;
    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Just be careful of a buffer overflow, since the user could enter more than 15 characters!  You can use `cin.get()` to mitigate that:

```cpp
cin.get(filename, 15);
```

Though, you really should be using `std::string` instead of `char[]`, eg:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool = 1, std::string filename = "");

//...

int fileOut(bool output, std::string filename){
    cin >> filename;
    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Either way, what is the point of letting the user pass in an input string if the function is just going to overwrite it?  If the function always prompts the user, then just use a local variable instead of a parameter:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool = 1);

//...

int fileOut(bool output){
    char filename[15] = {};
    cin.get(filename, 15);
    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool = 1);

//...

int fileOut(bool output){
    std::string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, if you want the caller to be able to provide a filename, and then prompt the user if no filename is given, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool = 1, char filename[15] = 0);

//...

int fileOut(bool output, char filename[15]){
    char buffer[15] = {};
    if (!filename) filename = buffer;

    if (*filename == 0)
        cin.get(filename, 15);

    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
int fileOut(bool = 1, std::string filename = "");

//...

int fileOut(bool output, std::string filename){
    if (filename.empty())
        cin >> filename;

    cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```