# replace the two largest elements of an array, inputed by user

Tags: c++

So basically i need to replace the two largest elements of an array, inputed by user. I don't understand why doesn't my code working.

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    double Max (double a[], int n) { 
    double max1=0, max2=0;
    
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(max1 < a[i]){
            max2 = max1;
            max1 =a[i];}
        else
            if(max2 < a[i]){
            max2 = a[i];}
    }
    return max2,max1;
    }
    
    int main () { 
    setlocale(0,".1251");
    double a[7];
    cout<<"Input 7-digit array:\n";
    
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) cin >> a[i];
    
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
    }
    
    system ("pause>>void");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: As an initial matter, `Max` is never actually called.

Comment: What do you expect `return max2,max1;` to do for a function that returns a `double` (just **one** double)?

Comment: Unrelated: `system ("pause>>void");` will create a file called `void` in some environments.

Comment: Max is never actually called and you are returning value no setting/returning max2 and max1.

Comment: @AdrianMole what variable should i return?

Comment: You have to change your function signature to allow for returning 2 doubles `std::pair<double,double> Max (double a[], int n)` is one option.

Comment: Related question that solves the returning 2 values from a function problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Comment: Nobody knows what value you "should return", you need to figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The function `double Max (double a[], int n)` is only defined, but you haven't called it. As it is right now, you are only outputting the same digits you inputted.
Also `double Max (double a[], int n)` can only return 1 double, so I'm assuming you were trying to return two variables `return max2,max1;` at once which isn't supported.
A fix to this could be by using a std::vector as data type and returning a 2 element array of `max1` & `max2` and then you would have to finish the code by actually calling the `double Max (double a[], int n)` function.

```
vector Maximums = Max(a[],7);
cout<< "\n max 1:\n" << Maximums[0] << "\n max 2:\n" << Maximums[1]
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to use something else except vector to solve this task?

Comment: ***But is there a way to use something else except vector to solve this task*** Yes the pair I showed in the comments of the question is also a way.