# How do I make an array of Vector2f from SFML?

Tags: c++, arrays, sfml

I don't know how to make an array with `Vector2f` from SFML.
It only works partially, it only works for the last variable returned.

```cpp
Vector2f apple()
{
    Vector2f s(2,4);
    Vector2f f(2,4);
    return s,f;
};
```

`s` would be equal to `0,0` and `f` would be normal.

Comment: Your stated return type, `Vector2f`, is **not** an array.

Comment: *"it only works for the last variable returned"* -- what does this mean? What does "work" mean when none of your variables is an array? I think your question needs more text describing what your expectations are, what you think your code does, and what your code actually does. A useful pattern for this kind of question is to **1)** Describe at a high, abstract level what you are trying to accomplish. **2)** Focus on your specific example case and describe how you want that example to work. **3)** Proved a [mre] for your example case. **4)** Give the expected and actual output.

Comment: *"`s would be equal to 0,0 and f would be normal`"* -- The only `s` variable I see is initialized to `2,4`. If you mean that you see `0,0` in the function that calls `apple()`, then that code should be part of your [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you're not able to return multiple values from a function like you're trying to do here:

```
return s,f;
```

There's many ways you could return multiple objects from a function:

### std::make_pair

You could utilise [std::make_pair](https://cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/) to return both `Vector2f`'s, like so:

```
std::pair<Vector2f, Vector2f> apple() {
    Vector2f s(2, 4);
    Vector2f f(2, 4);
    return std::make_pair(s, f);
}
```

Now, you can retrieve both values by doing:

```
std::pair<Vector2f, Vector2f> result = apple();
Vector2f s = result.first;
Vector2f f = result.second;
```

### std::vector

You can use std::vector (or std::array) to return multiple objects.

```
std::vector<Vector2f> apple() {
    Vector2f s(2, 4);
    Vector2f f(2, 4);
    return {s, f};
}
```

You can retrieve both of them doing:

```
std::vector<Vector2f> result = apple();
Vector2f s = result[0];
Vector2f f = result[1];
```

You could also use output parameters to hold the `Vector2f` result, but I'm sure the above two are sufficient in what you're trying to do.

This post here also covers your question: [Returning multiple values from a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)