# i don't know why my function doesn't return anything and my code doesn't work :(

Tags: c++, function, methods, return

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double Root(double a, double b, double c) {
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;

    if (delta > 0) {
        double x1 = (-b + sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        double x2 = (-b - sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
        cout << "x1 is : " << x1 << " x2 is : " << x2 << endl;
    } else if (delta == 0) {
        double x1=(-b)/(2*a);
        cout<<"x = "<< x1 <<endl;
    }
    return (a, b, c);
}

int main() {
    double a, b, c;

    while (true) {
       cout << "Enter a, b, c: ";
       cin >> a >> b >> c;

        if (a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) {
            break;
        }

        Root(a, b, c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i tried to return different things but still won't work

Comment: Your function signature says it returns 1 double. You must return only 1 double. The comma operator does not work like you think.

Comment: Why are you trying to return `a` , `b` and `c` which you don't change?

Comment: so how can i show the results in my function?

Comment: Your function should already output the results to the console however if you run your program from a GUI file manager you won't see the result because the console will close after the program finishes on most systems.

Comment: do i even need to return? to show the results?

Comment: You could have declared the function as `void Root(double a, double b, double c) {` and removed the return since it returns information that you don't need. Note that it's important to switch the function signature to `void Root(double a, double b, double c) {` because the original code required that you returned a double. If the code promises to return a value and violates that promise you have UB and a broken program

Comment: The problem you observe (if you don't see the output printed) may be this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529617/how-to-stop-c-console-application-from-exiting-immediately)

Comment: your code works here https://godbolt.org/z/bGo6rWKKo. Your return from the function is messed up, but anyhow you ignore the returned value. Whats the issue actually? What exactly do you mean with "still won't work" ?

Comment: when `delta < 0` the function produces no output. It that the issue?

Comment: @KaT You are trying to implement the quadratic formula, that's a formula with returns zero, one or two values. There is your first problem, you cannot (easily) make a function in C++ return differing numbers of values. Functions (speaking simply) return a single value. So you are trying to write a complicated function when you don't really understand how even simple functions work. So I think you need to pick an easier problem, pick a simpler formula to work with, say the area of a triangle. Practice with something like that until you've got the very basics of how functions work.

Comment: Functions can return nothing or **only one value**. You can either return a structure that has multiple fields or modify parameters (pass by reference).  You don't use the return value in `main`, so you should declare the function to return `void`.

Answer (score 2):

you can't return multiple values like you're doing with `return (a, b, c)` it's not allowed in c++. Try passing the arguments by reference or returning them in a list or container. Also you're returning something from the function but not assigning it to any variable and you're not changing the values in the function so there's no point in returning them in the first place. Check out this post [returning multiple values in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321068/returning-multiple-values-from-a-c-function)

Comment: i wanted to calculate the numbers in root function and show it in main, how do i do this?

Comment: pass the arguments by reference and actually do operations to change them inside the function, you don't even need to return something other than void

Comment: or just don't. You're already printing the values inside the function, no need to return anything if you're not using them outside

Comment: and how can i call my function in main?

Comment: To be slightly obscure, `return (a, b, c);` is legal and is equivalent to `return c;`. +1.

Comment: Returning a `tuple` and receiving with [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) can also be a viable option.